# How do I get the parents of a specific element?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get all the parents (that have the class "parent") of an element (that have the class "active"), and then apply a style to it. But it doesn't seem to find the elements that I request for.

This is the HTML that I'm currently using:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="parent">
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="active">Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I'm using the following Javascript file to apply a style to all the parents with the class "parent" of the starting element with the class "active":

```js
function openList() {
  el = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  while (el.parentNode) {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (el.className === "parent") {
      el.style.display="block";
    }
  }
}

window.onload = openList();
```

It is not returning anything, neither errors, but seems to be running.

Comment: `el.className === "parent"` is a check that will fail if that element has more than one class. `el.classList` is very helpful for this ...

Comment: `window.onload = openList();` <-- wrong

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: You might want `el.parentElement.parentElement` seen as it 2 nodes up the tree.  Or you could do `el.parentElement.closest("li")` if the parent is higher up the dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with the code.

- List item `getElementsByClassName` return `HTMLCollection` you should access its first element by using `[0]`
- You setting window.onload to `return` of the function `openList`. Just don't call the function i.e remove `()`

**Note**:You are declaring `el` as a global variable. use `let` `var` or `const` for declaring.

```js
function openList() {
  let el = document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0];
  while (el.parentNode) {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (el.className === "parent") {
      el.style.display="block";
    }
  }
}

window.onload = openList;
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="parent">
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="active">Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: depending on how large your html is it might be a better approach to get all elements with class 'parent' and see if they have a childElement with class 'active'

Comment: I don't see how can that be a better approach than this @jonathanHeindl Also @MaheerAli should use classlist like `element.classList.contains(class);`

Answer (score 0):

First you are calling the function and assigning what it returns to the

querySelector(), closest(), and classList would be the best way to handle this

```js
document.querySelector("li.active")
  .closest(".parent")
    .classList
      .add("open");
```

```css
li.parent {
  display: none;
}

li.parent.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="parent">
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="active">Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If there is more than one

```js
document.querySelectorAll("li.active").forEach(element =>
  element
   .closest(".parent")
    .classList
      .add("open")
)
```

```css
li.parent {
  display: none;
}

li.parent.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="parent">
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="active">Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="parent">
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="active">Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function openList() {
  
  let el = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(el,(parentNode)=>{
    if(parentNode.getElementsByClassName('active').length>0){
         parentNode.style.display="block";
    }
  });
}

window.onload = openList;
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="parent">
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="active">Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I propose this approach since its probably better runtime behaviour